# The two water bottle puzzle

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge

## Puzzle Question :

> Giving 2 bottle of water. The capacity of the first one was 3 liter
>   and the second one is 4 liter. They are all empty at first : `(0,0)`.
>   Each move only allow to do only one action at time.
>
> Find out the move to get the second bottle have 2 liter of water and
>   the first one can be anything (not overflow or negative) : `(n,2)` and `n`
>   in `[0,3]`.
>
> Short version : `(0,0)` > Do something > `(n,2)`, `n` in `[0,3]`

## Requirement :

Print out the first met target path (depend on generate tree approach)

Print out all target path to target

## My Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var BOTTLE1_WATER_CAPACITY = 3;
var BOTTLE2_WATER_CAPACITY = 4;
var chart = null; // No chart has been draw

function queue() {
    this.originalStack = [];
    this.dequeueStack = [];

    this.enqueue = function(value) {
        if (!value)
            throw new Error("Invalid value. Can't enequeue");
        this.originalStack.push(value);
    };

    this.enqueueArray = function(array) {
        if (!(array instanceof Array))
            throw new Error("Invalid value. Can't enqueue");
        for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) this.enqueue(array[i]);
    };

    this.dequeue = function() {
        if (!this.dequeueStack.length) {
            for (var i = 0, length = this.originalStack.length; i < length; i++)
                this.dequeueStack.push(this.originalStack.pop());
        }

        var childNode = this.dequeueStack.pop();
        return (childNode) ? childNode : new Error("Queue is empty");
    };
}

function Node(_Bottle1Water, _Bottle2Water, _ParentNode) {

    var getOverFlowWater = function(fillWater, currentWater, maxWater) {
        var overflow = (fillWater + currentWater) - maxWater;
        return (overflow > 0) ? overflow : 0;
    };

    this.childNode = [];
    this.ParentNode = (_ParentNode instanceof Node) ? _ParentNode : null;
    this.Bottle1Water = _Bottle1Water;
    this.Bottle2Water = _Bottle2Water;
    this.isParentOfTargetNode = false;
    this.getChildNode = function() {
        if (!this.childNode.length) {
            //Hoist
            var overflow;
            //Fill full
            if (this.Bottle1Water < 3)
                this.childNode.push(
                    new Node(
                        3, this.Bottle2Water, this));

            if (this.Bottle2Water < 4)
                this.childNode.push(
                    new Node(
                        this.Bottle1Water, 4, this));

            //Remove all water
            if (this.Bottle1Water > 0)
                this.childNode.push(
                    new Node(
                        0, this.Bottle2Water, this));

            if (this.Bottle2Water > 0)
                this.childNode.push(
                    new Node(
                        this.Bottle1Water, 0, this));

            //Fill water to another bottle
            if (this.Bottle1Water > 0 &&
                this.Bottle2Water < 4) {
                overflow = getOverFlowWater(
                    this.Bottle1Water,
                    this.Bottle2Water,
                    BOTTLE2_WATER_CAPACITY
                );

                this.childNode.push(
                    new Node(
                        overflow, this.Bottle2Water +
                        this.Bottle1Water - overflow, this));
            }

            if (this.Bottle2Water > 0 &&
                this.Bottle1Water < 3) {
                overflow = getOverFlowWater(
                    this.Bottle2Water,
                    this.Bottle1Water,
                    BOTTLE1_WATER_CAPACITY
                );
                this.childNode.push(
                    new Node(
                        this.Bottle1Water +
                        this.Bottle2Water - overflow, overflow, this));
            }
        }

        return this.childNode;
    };

    this.toString = function() {
        return "(" + this.Bottle1Water + "," + this.Bottle2Water + ")";
    };

    this.equal = function(Node) {
        return (this.Bottle1Water === Node.Bottle1Water &&
            this.Bottle2Water === Node.Bottle2Water);
    };

    this.isCycleNode = this.isCycleNode || function(afterDequeueArr) {
        for (var i = 0, length = afterDequeueArr.length; i < length; i++)
            if (this.equal(afterDequeueArr[i])) {
                this.isCycleNode = true;
                return true;
            }

        this.isCycleNode = false;
        return false;
    };

    this.isTargetNode = this.isTargetNode || function() {
        this.isTargetNode = (this.Bottle2Water === 2);
        return this.isTargetNode;
    };

    this.setParentOfTargetNode = function() {
        if (this.isTargetNode) {
            var cur = this.ParentNode;
            while (cur) {
                cur.isParentOfTargetNode = true;
                cur = cur.ParentNode;
            }
        }
    };
}

var BFS_MapAllPath = (function(initNode, callBack) {
    this.RootNode = initNode;
    this.TargetNode = [];

    //Attempt to implement queue using 2 stack
    var afterDequeueArr = [];
    _queue = new queue();
    _queue.enqueue(this.RootNode);

    var NodeReturnByQueue = _queue.dequeue();
    while (!(NodeReturnByQueue instanceof Error)) {
        if (NodeReturnByQueue.isTargetNode()) {
            this.TargetNode.push(NodeReturnByQueue);
            //Trace back to it's parent and set it as target path ()
            NodeReturnByQueue.setParentOfTargetNode();
        }

        if (!NodeReturnByQueue.isCycleNode(afterDequeueArr)) {
            var childNode = NodeReturnByQueue.getChildNode();
            _queue.enqueueArray(childNode);
        }

        afterDequeueArr.push(NodeReturnByQueue);
        NodeReturnByQueue = _queue.dequeue();
    }

    return {
        RootNode: this.RootNode,
        TargetNode: this.TargetNode
    };

})(new Node(0, 0));

function getEarliestPathAsString() {
    var TargetNode = BFS_MapAllPath.TargetNode[0];
    var childNodeString = "";

    //Trace from childNode to RootNode element
    while (TargetNode) {
        childNodeString = TargetNode.toString() + " > " + childNodeString;
        TargetNode = TargetNode.ParentNode;
    }

    return childNodeString.substring(0, childNodeString.length - 3);
}

function getAllTargetAsPathString() { //Complicated string
    var childNodeArr = BFS_MapAllPath.TargetNode;
    var childNodeString = "";

    for (var i = childNodeArr.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {

        childNodeString = childNodeArr[i].toString() + "\n" + childNodeString;

        var cur = childNodeArr[i];
        while ((cur = cur.ParentNode)) {
            childNodeString = cur.toString() + " > " + childNodeString;
        }

        childNodeString = "SOLUTION " + (i + 1) + " : " + childNodeString;
    }

    return childNodeString;
}

}


$("#btnGetEaliestPath").click(function() {
    $("#txtGetEaliestPath").val(getEarliestPathAsString());
});

$("#btnGetAllTargetPath").click(function() {
    $("#txtGetAllTargetPath").val(getAllTargetAsPathString());
});
```

View this in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXWZLP).

## Additional question :

I know this is review code section. But i tempted to post it anyway.

- What is the shortest/fastest way to solve it ?
- Is there any heuristic available for this puzzle ?

Comment: There is a pretty simple solution: `(0,0) -> (3,0) -> (0,3) -> (3,3) -> (2,4)` This is most likely also the best solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_pouring_puzzle may provide a start re general issues, and googling "water jug problem" (no quotes) may provide additional references.

Comment: Some of the math behind this puzzle is explained in this video: https://youtu.be/0Oef3MHYEC0

Comment: are you allowed to empty a jug?

Comment: Yes, but only 1 action is allow per move eg : empty first jug or empty second jug

Comment: @Vogel612 that's not a solution since the task requires the _second_ bottle to contain the 2.

Comment: @RolandIllig emptying the second bottle and filling it with the two liters again seems like a trivial fix for that :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Observations

- Your algorithm uses a brute force with backtracking and history, which is a nice verification method to get all paths that don't include any cycles.
- As you can see, there are 2 solutions. Each solution requires to use a flow from one bottle to the other. One bottle is the main bottle that you fill with water and move its content to the other.

  1. (0,0) - (3,0) - (0,3) - (3,3) - (2,4) - (2,0) - (0,**2**)
  2. (0,0) - (0,4) - (3,1) - (0,1) - (1,0) - (1,4) - (3,**2**)
- I'm surprised to see your brute force does not exit early in the top path, starting with filling the 3 liter bottle, when reaching `(0, 2)`. Is this as designed?

<sub>[Bruce managed a variant](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2013/02/04/the-water-jug-riddle/) with 3 and 5 gallon, but they didn't show us how in the movie (it's the same principle). How would Chuck have done it?</sub>